# mocking a promise in jest mock module factory

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm writing some units tests and need to mock a named export from a file, but it doesn't seem to work when the export is a function that returns a promise.

For example, I have a module located at `lib/api.js` that exports a single function called `getFoo`, which itself returns axios.get('/foo').

In my tests, I want to mock the return value of `getFoo` to be a resolved promise with the foo payload, so I mock using a module factory:

```
import * as api from 'lib/api';
jest.mock('lib/api', () => ({
  getFoo: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('foo')),
});
```

and then in my test I want to assert that getFoo was called as part of larger process of chained promises.

```
it('getBar should call getFoo', () => {
  return getBar().then(() => {
    expect(api.getFoo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
})
```

The error I get here is `cannot read property 'then' of undefined`, as though the jest function used in the mocked module factory is not returning the promise.

If the return value for `getFoo` is not a promise, it works as expected. If I use `jest.fn()` as the value for getFoo, and then in the test itself mock the implementation...

```
it('getBar should call getFoo', () => {
  api.getFoo.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve("foo"));
  return getBar().then(() => {
    expect(api.getFoo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
})
```

...then it works. My understanding is that the jest.fn(() => {}) should just be a shorter way of defining the implementation, so I am not sure why I am getting the error. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

More Info:

The `lib/api` looks like this...

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const getFoo = (host: string, accessToken: string): Promise<{}> =>
  axios.get(`${host}/foo`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
  // return foo
  .then((response) => response.data)
  .catch(() => {
    throw new Error('Failed to load foo');
  });
```

When I console log the mocked `getFoo` function while the test is running, it shows up as...

```
getFoo function mockConstructor() {
  return fn.apply(this, arguments);                                                                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need to mock it before importing it:

```
jest.mock('lib/api');

import * as api from 'lib/api';
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried moving the import after but it doesn't seem to change the outcome. I'm not really even using `lib/api` in the test file itself so maybe I don't need to import it at all, but regardless I get the same error `could not read property then of undefined`.

Comment: Can you add what you are exporting in `lib/api`? Looks also you might not be exporting what you are trying to access.

Comment: I have just noticed a typo in your implementation but it is strange because it should return you an error:
```getFoo: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('foo'))```. You are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: sorry about that, I fixed it, the code above I just typed into SO by hand instead of copy+paste from the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200263/discussion-between-dez-and-donald-p).